# How to add Google search suggestions in android SearchView?

Tags: android, browser, google-search, google-suggest

I am trying to build an android browser. I have a SearchView on the action bar. I recently found a URL where Google respond with search suggestion in a format which is unknown to me. I want to know if this is possible to get this response in the search suggestions of my SearchView?

URL with google search suggestion responses : http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=SEARCHTERM

Comment: simply parse that xml response, you can use dom, sax or pull parsers

Comment: @pskink can you please answer the question explaining about that in a little bit more depth.. it would be a great help. thank you

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html